# My long-term visit single entry for Dubai is expiring on 8 September 2017. Won't it be a problem when I land on the last day?

Tags: indian-citizens, uae, visa-expiration

My visa is valid until 8 September 2017. My doubt is, is there an issue if I land on the day my visa expires?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make a convincing argument that you are leaving the same day. If you can - like having a ticket out - it should be fine.
Otherwise, they will assume you plan to overstay and may not let you in.